# Simple Layout Shadow in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, shadow

So I've been searching the web for a way to display a simple shadow for a layout, but there is no proper way to do that.
All I found was a workaround where you create a layout behind the one you want a shadow to be applied to, and then tweak it to be transparent and some other stuff.

Is there any other way to have a simple layout shadow without adding a whole new layout ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I've been able to come up with a solution to this problem, and that by adding a `View` below our famous layout, displaying a gradient from one color to another.
Usually, the **First** color would be some sort of dark grayish, and the **Second** one would be the color of the **background** (in my case, i'll be having a light gray background so it's not completely white).

[image: Layout + View]

The xml would go like this :

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/headerImage"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow" >
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
...
```

drop_shadow.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#404040"
        android:endColor="#F1F1F1"
        android:angle="270"
        >
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

I hope it'll help ;)

Comment: and what happens if you want a shadow on the bottom AND right of the view?

Comment: @StackOverflowed same thing : You're just gonna add another LinearLayout for the right shadow.

Comment: thank for nice answer..how can we implement transparent shadow color ?

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani in order to do an actual transparent shadow, you have to add an alpha value to the color values. So, for a half-transparent to transparent shadow, use `startColor=#80000000` and `endColor=#00000000` which makes a black half-transparent to black fully-transparent gradient.

Comment: Not such a great solution for ovals or circle shapes :-/

Comment: Clean and simple solution, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat` class which sets the elevation of a view using the static method `setElevation`. The class is a helper for accessing features in view introduced after API Level 4 in a backwards compatible fashion.

The base elevation is in pixels eg

```
View mFab = (View) findViewById(R.id.floating_button);
ViewCompat.setElevation(mFab, 12);
```

Answer (score 6):

For lollipop and above you can use [elevation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html).

For older versions:

Here is a lazy hack from:
http://odedhb.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-layout-shadow-without-9-patch.html

(toast_frame does not work on KitKat, shadow was removed from toasts)

just use:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
```

or:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
```

as a background

examples:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="I am a simple textview with a shadow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
        />
```

and with different bg color:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
        android:padding="4dp"
        >
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button shadow"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In this approach, if I want to add a shadow to a layout, then how do I use background="#123456" AS WELL AS drawable/toast frame for the same layout? I think its not possible to use the attribute twice. So how do I proceed?

Comment: Just wrap it with a LinearLayout like example 2.